# How to remove port number from url using aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer

I am using AWS. I am using springboot, route53 and ec2. I need to connect to my domain name via browser. Right now I am able to connect like this

http://domainName.com:8080 but I dont need to include 8080 in my url.

I want to connect to domain like this

http://domainName.com

Comment: The simplest answer is to run your service on port 80 instead of port 8080 via the `server.port` param.

Comment: I tried to apply that properties. But while running it is showing error

Comment: Are you using a load balancer? You added the tag but didn't specify if you are using one or not.

Comment: Yes I am using Application Load balancing

Comment: Then you simply need to configure your load balancer's listener port to be port `80`. You can leave your backend application (and target group settings) at port `8080`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57922025/how-to-do-port-forwarding-in-aws-alb

Comment: Did you figure this out I have the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following setting in the load balancer? After doing so, when you will open the site with HTTP://xyz without port number 8080, it will by default take 80 ports. After that, this rule will redirect it with 8080 port and this rule will redirect it with http://domainName.com:8080

[image: LBR Rule]